# Calls to constant time function iterating through Numpy array results in very slow code

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, numpy

I have the following code snippet, which essentially does the following:
Given a 2d numpy array, `arr`, compute `sum_arr`  as follow:

```
sum_arr[i, j] = arr[i, j] + min(sum_arr[i - 1, j-1:j+2]) if (i>0) else arr[i, j]
```

(reasonable indices for `j - 1 : j + 2` of course, all within `0` and `w`)

Here's my implementation:

```
import numpy as np

h, w = 1000, 1000 # Shape of the 2d array
arr = np.arange(h * w).reshape((h, w)) 

sum_arr = arr.copy()

def min_parent(i, j):
    min_index = j    
    if j > 0:
        if sum_arr[i - 1, j - 1] < sum_arr[i - 1, min_index]:
            min_index = j - 1
    if j < w - 1:
        if sum_arr[i - 1, j + 1] < sum_arr[i - 1, min_index]:
            min_index = j + 1    
    return (i - 1, min_index)


for i, j in np.ndindex((h - 1, w)):
    sum_arr[i + 1, j] += sum_arr[min_parent(i + 1, j)]
```

And here's the problem: this code snippet takes way too long to execute for only 1e6 operations (About 5s on average on my machine)

What is a better way of implementing this?

Comment: How much of a speedup are you looking for? Removing the function calls (i.e. just having the ifs being in the for loop) and making the loop in j be from 1 to w-1 and dealing with the edges cases separately gets me from taking 0.87 secs to 0.57 secs (or thereabouts)

Comment: I did try that and on my machine, this doesn't really provide me with a significant performance boost,
I tried measuring this again with the function now inline and I only improved my runtime from 5s to 4s, I was looking for something more efficient.
Also I am kinda surprised that you only take 0.87 seconds on the given code, granted my machine is a bit dated however this degree of performance difference is weird, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your operation is sequential across rows, within rows it is not. It is therefore easy to vectorize row-wise and keep only a 1D outer loop which in relative terms shouldn't incur too much overhead.

Indeed, doing so gives me a ~200x speedup:

```
5.2975871179951355   # OP
0.023798351001460105 # vectorized rows
```

And the code is actually quite simple:

```
import numpy as np

h, w = 1000, 1000 # Shape of the 2d array
arr = np.arange(h * w).reshape((h, w)) 

def min_parent(i, j, sum_arr):
    min_index = j    
    if j > 0:
        if sum_arr[i - 1, j - 1] < sum_arr[i - 1, min_index]:
            min_index = j - 1
    if j < w - 1:
        if sum_arr[i - 1, j + 1] < sum_arr[i - 1, min_index]:
            min_index = j + 1    
    return (i - 1, min_index)

def OP():
    sum_arr = arr.copy()

    for i, j in np.ndindex((h - 1, w)):
        sum_arr[i + 1, j] += sum_arr[min_parent(i + 1, j, sum_arr)]
    return sum_arr

def vect_rows():
    h, w = arr.shape
    if w==1:
        return arr.cumsum(0)
    out = np.empty_like(arr)
    out[0] = arr[0]
    for i in range(1, h):
        out[i, :-1] = np.minimum(out[i-1, :-1], out[i-1, 1:])
        out[i, 1:] = np.minimum(out[i, :-1], out[i-1, 1:])
        out[i] += arr[i]
    return out

assert np.allclose(OP(), vect_rows())

from timeit import repeat

print(min(repeat(OP, number=3)))
print(min(repeat(vect_rows, number=3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic programming:
On a different array, precompute the mins for the blocks of  of size X (in your case you are doing it for size 3 (since you check j-1, j, j + 1). To determine the min for a block, use the value of the referenced position in the original array and the min of the previous block because you seem to be doing it dynamically.

This way you simply assign the index that needs it.